# Filtering Data by multiple value SQL

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, sqldf

i like to query/filter some data with multiple value using sql query. but i got nothing from it.
here is my code.

```
gd = cal.get_date()
dfd = datetime.strptime(gd, '%m/%d/%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

slspath = ('C:\\shgcgr\\RMWIN b4 patch 12.22.21\\SLS' + my + '.DBF')
slsdbf = DBF(slspath)
slsframe = DataFrame(iter(slsdbf))

dinerc = '1,4,5,7,8,13,14'

lunchdi = ps.sqldf("SELECT SUM(slsframe.total) AS 'netsales_for_lunch' From slsframe Where open_time >= '12:00:00' And open_time < '13:59:59' And date = '" + dfd + "'" + "And rev_center = '" + dinerc + "'")
lunchdidf = DataFrame(lunchdi)
print(lunchdidf)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give more info about your problem? Does the code rise error or return no data? If it returns no data, are you sure your query should return sth?

Comment: it returns to no data.

Comment: Have you tried to run the query on the server directly? I think this is the only way to understand if it is a server-side problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dinerc seems to be a list of rev_centers so you may need to use IN instead of = , try this:

```
lunchdi = ps.sqldf("SELECT SUM(slsframe.total) AS 'netsales_for_lunch' From slsframe Where open_time >= '12:00:00' And open_time < '13:59:59' And date = '" + dfd + "'" + "And rev_center IN (" + dinerc + ")")
```

Comment: thank you very much. i get the output value that i want.